# GEF: How to separate Domain Information from Presentation Information with pre-defined third-party model?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I am in the process of developing a GEF `View` (which will later be evolving into a GEF `Editor`), and I'm doing so with the help of the [GEF Book](http://www.qualityeclipse.com/eclipse-gef).

In chapter 8.1 ("GEF Models") in the book, a model is constructed which **mixes *Domain Information* and *Presentation Information*** (which is generously admitted): `GenealogyElement` is the `abstract` superclass for the rest of the model objects (but one).

`GenealogyElement` takes care of the location, and location changes of its subclasses (`Person`, `Marriage`) and the like, which themselves include the actual domain information. Btw, the source code can be found on the [books website](http://www.qualityeclipse.com/qualityeclipse.book.samples.zip?attredirects=0).

I wouldn't mind doing so myself (even if this is probably "bad style"), but I'm using a **third-party model which I cannot alter**, i.e., I cannot change the class `ThirdPartyNode` to extend, say, `ExampleElement`.

One option would of course be to write my own model against the third-party one, create an `abstract` class `ExampleElement`, and let a new class `ExampleNode` extend both `ExampleElement` and `ThirdPartyNode`. I might end up doing so, but really want to include different possibilities first, as creating another model is a lot of typing, and potentially superfluous (isn't it?).

What are my options for seperating both information types?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a similar problem creating a different model containing the presentation data (i.e: the position of the element) and a reference to the actual data model. 
You only shoud consider carefully how the data model notifies its changes to the editor.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please give me a starting point for creating such a model? Some basic code or class/method examples? Would be great. Your answer confirms the basic idea I had about solving this, but - especially with the "reference to the actual data model" - can't figure out how to start.

Comment: you culd take a look at ecore model editor: you can find it in the ecore tool repository http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Ecore_Tools